# Marginal probabilities.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Consider random variables X and Y with joint probability distributions, $$p(x,y)=\frac{e^{-4}3^x}{x!y!}$$

a) Find the marginal probabilities for X, $p_X(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty p(x_i,y_j)$

b) Compute the mean of the random variable X.

Okay, so obviously this can be solved with some help from the exponential power series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} = e^a$$

So for part a) I get

$$\frac{e^{-4}3^x}{x!}\sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{1}{y!}$$ the books shows this goes to

$$\frac{e^{-4}3^x}{x!}e^{1} = \frac{e^{-3}3^x}{x!}$$

but how does $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{1}{y!}=e^1$$, should I need to have $$\sum_{y=0}^\infty \frac{1^y}{y!}$$ to get e?

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you like, sure. But but you do have $1^y$ since $1=1^y$ for all $y$.

Comment: I was always taught that $e = 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!}+\cdots$ but that was a long time ago.